# Dynamixel multiple motor speed controller

Tags: ros, dynamixel-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to control some dynamixel motors (namely **MX 28** and **MX 64**) by there speed while not using 'goal_position'. In the [documentation](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-28.htm) is mentioned the **Wheel Mode** (by setting `CW = 0` and `CCW =0`) which I suppose is designed for my needs.

I can't find any `joint_speed_controller` in the `dynamixel_motor` pkg. Did anyone found or wrote its own joint speed controller?

If not, I'v seen the functions `set_speed(self, servo_id, speed)` in `dynamixel_io.py` but I'm not sure what is required to be set in a jont_speed_controller node. Can someone help me in this?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution to control a single motor velocity, but now I'm interested if I would be able to control multiple  motor velocities with a single controller. In the `dynamixel_io.py` there is a function: `def set_multi_speed(self, valueTuples)` which should be used for this task.

My main question is, should I reuse the already existing `JointController` class or build one on my own?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227426/dynamixel-multiple-motor-speed-controller/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-10-31**:
Hi, How did you manage to use a velocity control? Or did you manage in increasing the number of revolution the motor can perform?

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2016-10-31**:
I created a modified dynamixel_motor driver, you can find it here: https://bitbucket.org/ElodP/dynamixel-velocity-controller

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-10-31**:
What should I write if I only have one motor that I wish to run with with a speed controller?
Thanks

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2016-10-31**:
In a yam save motor parameters e.g. `JointSpeedController_2motors.yam`, in the `control_spawner` create only one and  the `controller_manager` can be the same as int he 2 motor example. Check out the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-11-01**:
Thanks a lot, it works. Is there a way to set the min angle limit to infinity? When publishing a positive value it turns non stop CCW (which is good), however, when publishing a negative value it stops after a serveral degrees ("At end MN True" appears in manager). Any ideas why?

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2016-11-01**:
I just add this feature and pushed to the repo. I did not test if it works well, so please let me know if there is any problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'v created a joint velocity controller and a multiple joint velocity controller, the modified dynamixel_motor pkg can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/ElodP/dynamixel-velocity-controller/overview

Details are in the README. For more information feel free to contact me.

Notice: `Min Angle` (CW) and `Max Angle` (CCW) **are not the same as **`minAngle` and `maxAngle` parameters. The first pair is the original parameters for CW and CCW, while the second pair of params are specific for my velocity controller applied on a robot arm that has physical angle limits.

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0